# UDPclient периодически перестаёт видеть поток

Tags: c#, udp

Есть приложение которое получает поток UDP из сети на скоростях от 50 до 90 мбит и параллельно его обрабатывает.
В процессе тестирования этого приложения столкнулся с тем, что во время длительных прогонов ( 10-20 часов) появляются ошибки вида:

```
    Вызвано исключение: "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException" в System.Net.Sockets.dll
[07.09.2021 11:00:42.910] [EXCEPTION] in [Exception while trying receive multicast group: 225.1.1.3] [System.Net.Sockets.Socket] [ReceiveFrom] [Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера.] 
Вызвано исключение: "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException" в System.Net.Sockets.dll
[07.09.2021 11:00:45.946] [EXCEPTION] in [Exception while trying receive multicast group: 225.1.1.3] [System.Net.Sockets.Socket] [ReceiveFrom] [Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера.] 
Вызвано исключение: "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException" в System.Net.Sockets.dll
[07.09.2021 11:00:48.980] [EXCEPTION] in [Exception while trying receive multicast group: 225.1.1.3] [System.Net.Sockets.Socket] [ReceiveFrom] [Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера.]
```

Ошибки возникают примерно 2-4 раза за 1 час работы. То есть 2-4 раза теряем поток на секунд 30- 40. Изначально я думал что в этот момент отваливается udp поток и не придавал значения этим ошибкам. Сегодня начал изучать их более детально и выяснил что во время возникновения ошибки в приложении, поток фактически приходит на компьютер. Wireshark этот поток видит.
Вот так работает приём udp потока:

Запускаем:

```
McastReceive = Task.Run(() => GetTsPacketsFromUdpStream());
```

Далее:

```
private void GetTsPacketsFromUdpStream()
    {
        try
        {
            udpClient = new UdpClient();

            var listenAddress = string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_listenerAddress) ? IPAddress.Any : IPAddress.Parse(m_listenerAddress);

            var localEp = new IPEndPoint(listenAddress, m_macstPort);

            udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            udpClient.Client.ReceiveBufferSize = 1500 * 3000;
            udpClient.Client.ReceiveTimeout = 3000;
            udpClient.Client.Bind(localEp);
            udpClient.JoinMulticastGroup(IPAddress.Parse(m_mcastAddress), listenAddress);

            Task.Run(() => Receive(udpClient)).ContinueWith(AfterMcastStop);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Send(LogStatus.Exception, "Get packets from udp stream exception", ex);
        }

    }
```

Ну и вот этот метод выдаёт ошибки:

```
private void Receive(UdpClient udpClient)
    {

        while (!m_stopWoriking)
        {
            try
            {

                var ep = udpClient.Client.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
                var data = udpClient.Receive(ref ep);
                RingBuffer.Add(ref data);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Send(LogStatus.Exception, $"Exception while trying receive multicast group: {m_mcastAddress}", ex);
            }

        }

        Logger.Send(LogStatus.Info, $"Multicast receiving stopped");
    }
```

Поток отваливается на 30-40 секунд. Так как приём осуществляется в цикле ошибки идут эти 30-40 секунд и далее приём и обработка пакетов восстанавливаются.
Фактически UDP мультикаст не прерывается, просто по какой-то причине Udpclient перестаёт его видеть и начинает кидать исключения. Других ошибок приложение не выкидывает. Общая нагрузка на CPU в этот момент не превышает 10%. Сеть тоже не нагружена. Также запускал в этот момент VLC плеер. Он  поток видит. Подскажите, с чем может быть связанно такое поведение? И как это исправить.

Comment: Очень интересная ситуация. А у Вас это под виндой запущено или под линуксом? И какая версия фреймворка? А повторяется ли ситуация на машине с другой конфигурацией железа? Чисто на уровне интуиции кажется - что то нехорошее происходит с этим дескриптором сокета на уровне OS. Как бы это проверить? Если руки дойдут - я попробую смоделировать ситуацию...

Comment: Версия фреймворка 4.8.04084. Windows 10. на других машинах ещё не проверял

Comment: Пора бы слезать уже с древних 4.x фреймворков.

Comment: на сервере с windows server 2016 такие ошибки тоже возникали. но гораздо реже. последняя была вчера в 15:09. не понятно был ли поток в это время или нет. нужно придумать какой-то инструмент для этого. Wireshark на таких скоростях потока зависает через пару минут.